# Pass environment variables to a Livy/PySpark job

Tags: pyspark, environment-variables, livy

I have a PySpark job that I submit to Livy via [Livy's HttpClient](https://github.com/cloudera/livy/blob/master/python-api/src/main/python/livy/client.py), and I would like to pass some environment variables to it.
I'm currently using a workaround in which the submitted code updates its `os.environ` manually.

Is there a better way to do it, so that I would have all the environment variables that I want right off the bat, i.e. when the Livy session is created?